# Time complexity of finding subsequences of a string segmented into parts

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, subsequences

Let $S$ be a string of length $N$, consisting of digits 0 to 9.
For convenience, we assume $N$ to be a multiple of 3.

Then, we split $S$ into $N/3$ equal parts, each of length 3.

For each equal part, we count/enumerate all subsequences of all lengths up to 3.

Finally, we total up how many such subsequences are there altogether.

What is the time complexity of the above algorithm? Thanks.

I give a more concrete example in case the above is not clear. Suppose $S=`111211'$, of length 6.

We first split it into 2 parts $`111'$ and $`211'$. For the first part $`111'$, we  count that there are 3 subsequences of $`11'$ (note that subsequences do not have to be consecutive unlike substrings), for the $`211'$, there is 1 subsequence of $`11'$, so in total there are 4 subsequences of $`11'$. We do this for all possible subsequences up to length 3, even for subsequences that do not appear such as $'000'$, we count that it occurs zero times.

---

I am new to time complexity, but I did try to calculate it myself. For each part of length 3, the time complexity of enumerating the subsequences is $O(1)$? Hence, in total, we have to repeat it $N/3$ times, so the overall time complexity is $O(N)$?
Is that correct? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your analysis is correct.